# Recording voice in a while loop using Tkinter

Tags: python, while-loop, tkinter, audio-recording

I'm coding a voice recording application and I want to start the recording when the user pushes a Button in Tkinter, and stop the recording when the user releases the Button.

```
import Tkinter

def record():
    while True
          Recordning runtines...
          if <button is released>
             stop audio steam...
             break


main = Tkinter.Tk()

b = Tkinter.Button(main, text='rec', command=record)
b.place(x="10", y="10")

main.mainloop()
```

How do I achieve the "if button is released"? Do I need to use Threading?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to freeze the GUI while recording, I recommend you to use multithreading. The click and release of the button can be accomplished with the events [`<Button-1>` and `<ButtonRelease-1>`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm#events). I have wrapped the code into a class, so it also contains the flag for finishing the working thread.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import threading

class App():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.isrecording = False
        self.button = tk.Button(main, text='rec')
        self.button.bind("<Button-1>", self.startrecording)
        self.button.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.stoprecording)
        self.button.pack()

    def startrecording(self, event):
        self.isrecording = True
        t = threading.Thread(target=self._record)
        t.start()

    def stoprecording(self, event):
        self.isrecording = False

    def _record(self):
        while self.isrecording:
            print "Recording"

main = tk.Tk()
app = App(main)
main.mainloop()
```