# Tkinter, when button pressed (not released), do command

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I'm using Python 2.7.13 with Tkinter.

This is part of my program:

```
PAButton = Tkinter.ButtonPress(PAFrame, text='PA', fg='white', bg='blue')
PAButton.pack()
self.PAButton.bind("<ButtonPress>", self.playPA)
```

---

This is the gist of what I am trying to do:

*When PAButton is pressed (not released), run the function `playPA()` as defined earlier in the script.*

---

However, I get this **error**:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ButtonPress'
```

How would I correctly accomplish my goal?

Comment: ... please, do research.

Comment: Are you sure that `Tkinter` has a `ButtonPress` method, but I didn't find it.

Comment: @S.G.Harmonia I did. I found [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522095/gui-button-hold-down) and [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548757/how-can-i-identify-when-a-button-is-released-in-tkinter) and I based my code off of that. Please, don't comment rashly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as `ButtonPress`. It's `Button`.

**EDIT:** For the `.bind()` function, instead of `"<ButtonPress>"`, use `"<Button-1>"`.

Comment: However, the command only occurs when the button is released. How could I run a command when the button is pressed?

Comment: Using your edit, I had to write `playPA()` like this: `PAButton.bind("<Button-1>", playPA())` because I got an error: `TypeError: playPA() takes no arguments (1 given)`. 

However, when I run the program now, the playPA() function occurs before the GUI starts and nothing happens when I press the PAButton.

Comment: In a func bind using `bind()`, you are not supposed to add `()` to the end of the func name. Also, if you haven't already, add `event` to the arguments of your function.

Comment: This solved the issue. Thank you!