# calling a function in python after mouse release & closing the tkinter window after selcting a option from it

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to call a function in python after a mouse release button.Currently I am calling the same function after the key 'a' is pressed.Also I want to close tkinter window automatically after a option is selected. Here is my code:

```
def onkeypress1(event):
 if event.key == 'a':
  def option_changed(*args):
     c=variable.get()
     object_list.append(c)
     print c
     return c


  master = Tk()
  variable = StringVar(master)
  variable.set("select") # default value
  variable.trace("w", option_changed)

  w = OptionMenu(master, variable, "INDIA", "USA", "UK")
  w.pack()

  mainloop()
```

I want to call function onkeypress1() after the mouse release button.

Comment: `<ButtonRelease-1>`

Comment: Your question doesn't include a question. You've explained what you're wanting to do, but didn't explain what part of the problem you need help with.

Comment: The  answer by Billal worked for me but I also want to close the tkinter window after the option are selcted from it.

Comment: master.destroy() is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a binding for the ButtonRelease event. A question like yours has been answered here: [How can I identify when a Button is released in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548757/how-can-i-identify-when-a-button-is-released-in-tkinter?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: one more question i have, how can I close the tkinter window after selecting a option(INDIA,USA etc) from it?

Comment: @sultan Sorry, I do not have an answer for that problem

Answer (score 0):

-call a function after mouse release and close tkinter after choose an option

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, OptionMenu, StringVar

class App(Frame):
    '''Class App'''
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        """ init App """
        Frame.__init__(self, master, bg="dim grey")
        self.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.onkeypress1) # call function after mouse release
        self.pack(ipadx=50,ipady=50)
        self.variable = StringVar()
        self.variable.set("Select") # default value

        #trace(mode, callback) mode 'w' = call if variable is written
        self.variable.trace("w", self.option_changed) 

        w = OptionMenu(self, self.variable, "INDIA", "USA", "UK")
        w.pack()

    def onkeypress1(self,event):
        print("jo")

    def option_changed(self, *args):
        c=self.variable.get()
        print(c)
        if self.variable != "Select":
            self.master.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
    print("it runs further")
```