# Create label in tkinter and update the Label with an int variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to create a label and update it with the int-value, which is updated by pressing the buttons, also in the label. I'm still new to Python and would like some help :)

```
import tkinter as tk

class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.integer = tk.IntVar()
        self.integer.set(0)

        tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.destroy).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='+', command=self.plus_one).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='-', command=self.take_one).pack()

        self.entry0 = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=str(self.integer), justify="center", width=4)
        self.entry0.pack()

    def plus_one(self):
        x =  self.integer.get() + 1
        self.integer.set(x)

    def take_one(self):
        x =  self.integer.get() - 1
        self.integer.set(x)

app = Main()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the question? The code seems to work fine. Although the `as Numbers` bit of your `import` is quite counter-intuitive. I would have used `import tkinter as tk` and refactored the code accordingly.

Comment: You could replace numbers by tk :)
My question is how to create a label where the Int value is updated as soon as I press the + and - buttons.

Comment: Then perhaps you should update your question accordingly. Just to get this straight, is the question about button press vs button release? For me the code works on key press, but the update happens at button release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this the same way you did with the `Entry` widget:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.integer = tk.IntVar()
        self.integer.set(0)

        tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.destroy).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='+', command=self.plus_one).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='-', command=self.take_one).pack()

        self.entry0 = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=str(self.integer), justify="center", width=4)
        self.entry0.pack()

        self.label0 = tk.Label(self, textvariable=str(self.integer))
        self.label0.pack()

    def plus_one(self):
        x =  self.integer.get() + 1
        self.integer.set(x)

    def take_one(self):
        x =  self.integer.get() - 1
        self.integer.set(x)

app = Main()
app.mainloop()
```

---

As per your comments, if you are interested in having the binding at button press instead of button release, this has been already addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548757/how-can-i-identify-when-a-button-is-released-in-tkinter).