# Stop the reading of notes created with fluidsynth with a button in tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, fluidsynth

I'm on python2-7 I want to get a button in tkinter which stop the reading of the notes created with fluidsynth.

I found that the common solution is to use time.after like here: [How do you create a Tkinter GUI stop button to break an infinite loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050492/how-do-you-create-a-tkinter-gui-stop-button-to-break-an-infinite-loop)

But in my case I can't use it because I need an amount of time between noteon and noteoff to give durations for my notes.
Moreover I want to play the notes ONLY if I click on start (and no at the beginning like the solution in the link).

So I created this code but it doesn't work because var_start is always initialized as int:

```
from tkinter import*
import fluidsynth
import time

fs=fluidsynth.Synth()
fs.start(driver='alsa', midi_driver='alsa_seq')
org_charge = fs.sfload("organ.sf2")
fs.program_select(0,org_charge, 0, 0)
time.sleep(1)

var_start=int

def start():
    global var_start
    var_start=1

def stop():
    global var_start
    var_start=0

root=Tk()

if var_start==1:
    fs.noteon(0,67,127)
    time.sleep(1)
    fs.noteoff(0,67)
    fs.noteon(0,71,127)
    time.sleep(1)
    fs.noteoff(0,71)
    fs.noteon(0,74,127)
    time.sleep(1)
    fs.noteoff(0,74)

Button(root, text='start', command= start).pack(padx=10, pady=10)    
Button(root, text='stop', command= stop).pack(padx=10, pady=10)    

root.mainloop()
```

I don't have other idea to reshape my code...
Can someone help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initiated `var_start` to `int` in statement `var_start=int` and so the code block in `if var_start==1:` will never be executed.  And your `start()` function is just changing the `var_start` to 1 and never start playing the notes, therefore nothing will happen.

Never call `time.sleep()` in main thread as it will block the `tkinter` main loop.  You can use `.after(...)` to simulate the play loop and below is a sample code block:

```
playing = False

def play_notes(notes, index, noteoff):
    global playing
    if noteoff:
        fs.noteoff(0, notes[index])
        index += 1      # next note
    if playing and index < len(notes):
        fs.noteon(0, notes[index], 127)
        # call noteoff one second later
        root.after(1000, play_notes, notes, index, True)
    else:
        # either stopped or no more note to play
        playing = False
        print('done playing')

def start_playing():
    global playing
    if not playing:
        print('start playing')
        playing = True
        notes = [67, 71, 74, 88, 80, 91]
        play_notes(notes, 0, False)
    else:
        print('already playing')

def stop_playing():
    global playing
    if playing:
        playing = False
        print('stop playing')
    else:
        print('nothing playing')

Button(root, text='Start', command=start_playing).pack(padx=10, pady=10)
Button(root, text='Stop', command=stop_playing).pack(padx=10, pady=10)
```

It is just an example you can modify to suit your need.

Comment: Thanks for your help acw1668 ! It works perfectly now !