# python tkinter GUI sys exit does not work[multithreading added]

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

my code is mainly scraping pages by clicking `next` button. I wanted to add a button, when scraping continuously runs having possibility to stop it and exit running the main thread. - just stop program execution. I learnt from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050492/how-do-you-create-a-tkinter-gui-stop-button-to-break-an-infinite-loop)  better to run `thread` asynchronously then I would have a possibility to stop of execution and exit scraping in any moment.
threading added one fine thing that close `button` does not freeze any more when code is running in the background. But when I click to stop it, the screen  of GUI freezes and in background code runs...

`main` module;

```
...from tk_class_wdgs import *...
def start_app():
    create_sheets()
    def starting_scraping():
        conn(search_var[0])

    t=threading.Thread(target=starting_scraping)
    t.start()

if __name__=='__main__':
    tk_wdg=ClassWidgets()
    tk_wdg.btnS['command']=start_app
    tk_wdg.btnC['command']=sys.exit
    tk_wdg.root.mainloop()
```

`tk_class_wdgs` module;

```
import sys
from tkinter import *

class ClassWidgets():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=Tk()
        self.frm01=Frame(master=self.root,width=10,height=10,borderwidth=3,bg='red')
        self.frm01.pack(expand='YES',fill=BOTH)
        self.frm02=Frame(master=self.root,width=10,height=10,borderwidth=3,bg='blue')
        self.frm02.pack(expand='YES',fill=BOTH)
        self.btnC=Button(master=self.frm02,text='close',bg='yellow')
        self.btnC.pack(expand='YES',side='right')
        self.btnS=Button(master=self.frm02,text='scrape',foreground='green')
        self.btnS.pack(expand='YES',side='left')
        self.ent=Entry(master=self.frm01)
        self.ent.pack(expand='YES',side='top',fill=X,padx=5,pady=5)


if __name__=='__main__':
    tkinter_widgets=ClassWidgets()
    tkinter_widgets.root.title('scraper')
    tkinter_widgets.btnC['command']=sys.exit
    tkinter_widgets.root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can see if using root.destroy() and then sys.exit() works for you.

Comment: you are suggesting using one of `root.quit` or `root.destroy`. Because sys.exit does not worked. I am thinking of driver.quit can also be helpful in this instance

Comment: If you don't mind to terminate the process ungracefully, what about using ```os.exit()```?

Comment: `tk_wdg.btnC['command']=os.exit
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'exit'. Did you mean: '_exit'?`

Comment: Yes, my mistake. It's the ```os._exit()```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added new function, named `close_app`

```
def close_app():
    driver.quit()
    tk_wdg.root.quit()
    sys.exit()


if __name__=='__main__':
    tk_wdg=ClassWidgets()
    tk_wdg.btnS['command']=start_app
    tk_wdg.btnC['command']=close_app
    tk_wdg.root.mainloop()
```

first I `quit` driver, which is global variable, then I quit mainloop, then added also sys.exit(). Adding at first line `sys.exit()` freezes the screen, and on background loop runs. Don't know why
finishes everytime with such error'

`raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:  Stacktrace: Backtrace:`